# Set Mysql variable in magento

Tags: database

I want to fire select query which is as follows

```
SET @a = 0;
SELECT @a:=@a+1 as count FROM admin_user;
```

How I can add SET variable in SQL query in magento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have run this Query

```
/* Get the  core resource model */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

/*  Retrieve the read connection */
 $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
 $query = 'SELECT @cnt:= 0 ;';
 $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

Then Your Query i:e

SELECT @a:=@a+1 as count FROM admin_user;
```